# Convergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} \frac{x}{n^{\alpha}+x^2 n^{\frac{3}{2}}} $ subject to condition on $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Given:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{ \infty} \frac{x}{n^{\alpha}+x^2 n^{\frac{3}{2}}}, $$ I am to prove that this converges if $ \alpha > \frac{1}{2}$.

Help, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: What is $x$ doing here?

Comment: Have you heard of function series?

Comment: Hint: AM-GM inequality.

Comment: $$\left|\frac{x}{n^\alpha +x^2n^{3/2}}\right|\le \frac1{|x|} \,\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: "I don't even know where to start" This is quite odd. Which series do you know that are convergent, resp. divergent? The simplest possible ones...

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**. $\blacktriangleleft$ Suppose you are considering $x \in \mathbb R$. Clearly the series converges at $x =0$. For $x \neq 0$, consider to prove the absolute convergence: since 
$$
\frac {|x|}{n^\alpha + x^2 n^{3/2}} = \frac 1 {\dfrac {n^\alpha}{|x|} + |x|n^{3/2}} \leqslant \frac 1 {2 n^{3/4+\alpha/2}}, 
$$ 
and $3/4 +\alpha /2 >1$ for $\alpha >1/2$, hence the convergence on $\mathbb R. \blacktriangleright$

Response to you:

I was requiring more information from you, since $x$ could be anything. Example, $x\in \mathbb C$. Then your question might be pretty different.

Comment: $$\left|\frac{x}{n^\alpha +x^2n^{3/2}}\right|\le \frac1{|x|} \,\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks for this better solution

Comment: I think this is the flaw of the question design.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) between this series and the [hyperharmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{p}}$.

Distinguish between the cases $\alpha>\frac{3}{2}$ and the case $\frac{1}{2}<\alpha\leq \frac{3}{2}$.

For the first case you can compare with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}$ for $p=\alpha$. For the second, compare use $p=\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: I supposed so, but I tried to get there and failed

Comment: $$\left|\frac{x}{n^\alpha +x^2n^{3/2}}\right|\le \frac1{|x|} \,\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

Comment: @MarkViola Spamming everywhere that inequality doesn't make it true. Moreover, adding it without any text, explanation, or quantification makes it actually false. So, if you wanted to cause an impression, you did, the impression that you didn't think enough.

Comment: @theoldformulation The inequality holds.  Why do you believe otherwise?  And communicating with individuals can hardly be classified as "Spamming."  I suggest it is you who has made a bad first impression by posting an inane comment.  Inasmuch as you believe the inequality fails to hold, surely $n^\alpha>0\implies n^\alpha+x^2n^{3/2}>x^2n^{3/2}$.  Are you able to continue?

Comment: @MarkViola You are the one that is clearly unable to see when that inequality fails, which it does, right in the next step that you will try to do.

Comment: Oh?  And what next step?  Are you saying that for $x\le 0$, $\left|\frac{x}{n^\alpha+n^{3/2}}\right|\le \frac{1}{|x|n^{3/2}}$ fails?  Then it is you who is incorrect.

Comment: @MarkViola No, you still haven't seen it. Work on it. You should have taken more time thinking about it instead of plastering your inequality everywhere.

Comment: @theoldformulation ;-))  Show the error if you're so convinced that the inequality is wrong.  You are hilarious.   One user who posted a comment actually thanked me for posting the "better solution."   And Didier would've crucified anyone who posts nonsense.  Show the error and correct way forward or cease and desist your ridiculous harassment.

Comment: @theoldformulation Clearly, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ inasmuch as the series would be undefined for certain values of $x\in\mathbb{C}$.  Now, if we restrict $x$ as a complex number, the analysis can easily be modified.   The key point is that the summand is $O(n^{-3/2})$.  And your rude and offensive behavior has been flagged!